# Find line height within dynamically inserted element

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, browser

Within a particular div/span that I might dynamically insert into the DOM, I need to find the `1em` computed height(height after rendering) within that DOM element.

Just wanted to know if anyone already knows of a good way to do this before I start out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you want the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method. For example, here on Stack Overflow:

```js
$(document.body).css('line-height'); //-> "12px"
```

In 'vanilla' JavaScript you want [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) [[specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle)] for modern browsers, or [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231.aspx) for older IE versions.

Comment: Thank you.  But, `.css()` gives me `normal` or `undefined` or the stylesheet-defined height if explicitly specified. I will try `getComputedStyle()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @conqenator Post a sample test case on [JSFiddle](http://JSFiddle.net) - then others can butter understand what you want and also help achieve it.